# How to restore permanently deleted files from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I deleted file from Google Drive and later I deleted it from Trash also. Is there any way I can restore the files even after deleting from the Trash?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a Google Apps (for Work|Education|Government) account, your administrator should be able to restore the file. ([Restore a user's Google Drive or Gmail data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6052340))

If you just have a normal Google account, Google *may* be able to recover the file for you, but only for a limited time.

> If you’ve deleted a file or folder, Google will be able to help you recover a deleted file or folder for a limited time, but you must be the owner of the file or folder. You’re the owner if:
>
> - You created the file or folder in your Google Drive account
> - You uploaded the file or folder into your Google Drive account
> - The original owner transferred ownership to you and you accepted

Fill out [this Google support form](https://support.google.com/drive/contact/missing_items) with the necessary information, and Google *may* be able to recover the file(s) for you. There's no guarantee, however.

---

The whole point of having deleted files go to Trash instead of deleting outright is so that you can recover them if you make a mistake. Don't doubly compound it by removing it from your emergency recovery option. Also, consider not completely relying on Google Drive to keep your important files. Sync them locally and keep local backups as well.